# Twig Variable in Array

Tags: php, twig, symfony5

AuthContoller:

```
   return $this->render('pages/login.html.twig', [
        'LoginForm'  => $form->createView(),
        'lang'       => self::getStrings('en-en') // Returns an array,
        'message'    => $verify['string'],
    ]);
```

Normally I call a string in a twig template with `{{ lang.stringname }}`. In this case I want to call a string with the value, which was submitted via 'message'.

I tried this:

```
{{ lang[message] }}
```

and

```
{{ lang.[message] }}.
```

The error message is:

```
Expected name or number.
```

Does anyone have an idea? Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The dot notation is a shortcut for an array[] - particularly useful for named arrays, but can also be used for numeric-indexes as well as. Use of the regular array is still possible, and that can take an independent variable as the key.

```
{{ lang[message] }}
```

There is a [TwigFiddle](https://twigfiddle.com/g2bcem/40), based on one in @DarkBee's link to show it in use.